# Is it possible to install old version of NoMachine?

Tags: repository, software-sources, versions, downgrade, nomachine

My NoMachine on remote PC was auto-updated to 6 version. But my host machine require 5th (there are some specific issues with the newer one). And now it is not possible to connect from 5th to 6th.

Is it possible to obtain somewhere older version .deb file?
For windows there are a lot of storage web-pages. Is there any for linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a different problem. According to the nomachine website:

> Compatibility between client/server versions 5 or 4 and v. 6 is fully preserved.

A host with version 4, 5 or 6 should be able to interact with a server version 6.

---

If the owners of nomachine do not provide the old versions: no.

From their website it looks like you can only install their latest version. And I assume the installation of nomachine from Ubuntu is also done by adding their PPA and not through the Ubuntu repositories.

If that is the case there is not even a way back: re-installing Ubuntu for instance will then install the lastest nomachine version.

All in all if it is indeed compatibility: you need to upgrade the host.

---

Possible trick: use wget to pull their website and check if there are old DEBs on their system. I have not been able to find `nomachine_6.0.66_2_amd64.deb` (yet) though. If someone can find that it might be possible to download a  `nomachine_5.7.*_*_amd64.deb` and install that using dpkg.

Comment: Not fully - the option to connect using the key, not the password is not working on newer versions. Or at least does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect because you are using the 'NoMachine login' which comes from their legacy v3.

Adapted from their website:

Starting from version 6 the 'NoMachine login' authentication method is no longer an option in the NoMachine User Interface nor a configuration available in the NoMachine Server.

Since version 4 was released, new authentication options have been implemented in order to offer the most flexible and most secure integration with existing configurations available on the server host.

Dropping support for the 'NoMachine login' affects all servers using such method regardless of the version. It also means that compatibility with legacy version 3.5 is no longer available. Thus, any NoMachine Server version 6 or later will not accept connections from client version 3.x, and client version 6 or later will not offer the option to enable the 'NoMachine login' method.

I suggest you go to NoMachine and ask them kindly if they can help you get back to v5. Keeping a back up of the package will avoid the problem of 'accidentally' updating.

Comment: It seems I have found the old .deb files: https://styrion.at/apt/amd64/